# Unity Ошибка NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть класс SaveData

```
public class SaveData
{
public static SaveData current;


public Motive health;
public Motive eat;
public Motive sleep;


public SaveData()
{
    health = new Motive() { name = "health", value = 100 };
    eat = new Motive() { name = "eat", value = 100 };
    sleep = new Motive() { name = "sleep", value = 100 };

}
```

А есть класс Motives

```
public class Motives: MonoBehaviour {
public static Motives Instance { get; set; }

public bool hudOn;
public GameObject hudback;

public TextMesh HealthText;
public TextMesh EatText;
public TextMesh SleepText;
public GameObject HealthImg;

void Start()
{

    GameObject gma = GameObject.Find("DialogBox");
    gma.SetActive(true);
    hudOn = true;

    HudBar(-0.2f, 1.22f,  SaveData.current.health.value, SaveData.current.health.name);
    GameObject gm = GameObject.Find("DialogBox");
    gm.SetActive(false);
    hudOn = false;
}
public void HudBar(float xpos, float ypos, float scale, string names)
{
    GameObject gm = Instantiate(HealthImg, new Vector3(0.125f, 1.29f, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    gm.transform.SetParent(GameObject.FindWithTag("back_hud").transform);
    gm.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(xpos - xpos * (100 - scale)/100, ypos, 0);
    gm.name = names;
}
```

И на строчке

```
    HudBar(-0.2f, 1.22f,  SaveData.current.health.value, SaveData.current.health.name);
```

выдает ошибку NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Motives.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/Motives.cs:40)
Но при этом, если занести SaveData.current.health.value в переменную перед вызовом метода, и подставить эту переменную в вызов, то все работает корректно. Вопрос: как правильно использовать SaveData.current.health.value?

И конечно, сам Motive

```
public class Motive
{

public string name;
public float value;

public Motive()
{
    this.name = "";
    this.value = 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Что-то странно, так не должно быть. А покажите-ка всё исключение, а особенно stack trace из него.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы используете `SaveData.current.health.value`, но у вас `current` поле этого класса не инициализируется нигде, поэтому `null`.

Объявите класс так:

```
public class SaveData{

    private static SaveData current;


    public Motive health;
    public Motive eat;
    public Motive sleep;


    public SaveData(){
        health = new Motive() { name = "health", value = 100 };
        eat = new Motive() { name = "eat", value = 100 };
        sleep = new Motive() { name = "sleep", value = 100 };

    }

    public static  SaveData GetInstance(){
        if(current == nul){
            current = new SaveData();
        }

        return current ;
    }

}
```

А вместо  `HudBar(-0.2f, 1.22f,  SaveData.current.health.value, SaveData.current.health.name);`

напишите:

```
HudBar(-0.2f, 1.22f,  SaveData.GetInstance().health.value, SaveData.GetInstance.health.name);
```

Comment: Да, действительно. Премного благодарен!